# Datepicker only shows once in dynamic content

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I'm experiencing a strange problem when instantiating Datepicker with dynamic content.
Setup: HTML with PHP injection, programmed together with jQuery and AJAX.

I have [jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/trunk/com.mds.apg/resources/jqm/demo2/experiments/ui-datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js?r=92) running.

When I click on a link, it loads the page as it should. When I go back and click the link again, the datepicker doesn't show (the input field does have the 'hasDatepicker' class).

Now, I noticed if I'm on another page, go to the page with the link and then click it, it doesn't show the datepicker, not even the first time.

```
$('.productSaleLink').live('click',function() {
    var prod = $(this).attr('data-params');
    $.post("product.php",{product:prod}, function(data){
        $('#productContent').html(data);
        $.mobile.changePage('#productsale', {transition: 'slide'});
        $('.currentProduct').listview();
        $('.sellLink').button();
        $(':input').textinput();
        $('.date').datepicker().css({'background-color':'red'});
    });

    return false;
})
```

product.php:

```
$html = "<ul class='currentProduct' data-role='listview' data-theme='d' data-divider-theme='d'>";

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($products))
{
    $html .= "<li class='lis'>";
    $html .= "<h3>".$row2['brand']." ".$row2['product']."</h3>";
    $html .= "<p><span style='color:#666'>Serial:</span> <span style='font-weight:bold;'>".$row2['serial']."</span>,<span style='color:#666'> Product-ID:</span> ".$row2['product_id']."</p>";
    $html .= "<p><span style='color:#666'>Bought:</span> ".$row2['buying_date']."<span style='color:#666'> From:</span> <span style='font-weight:bold;'>".$row2['seller']."</span></p>";
    $html .= "<input class='client' style='display:inline;margin-right:5px;' type='text' name='client' id='client' value='Client' onfocus='if($(this).val()==\"Client\")$(this).val(\"\");' onblur='if($(this).val()==\"\")$(this).val(\"Client\");' />";
    $html .= "<input class='date' style='display:inline;' type='date' name='date' id='".$row2['id']."' value='Date' />";
    $html .= "<p class='ui-li-aside'>";
    $html .= "<a class='sellLink' data-params='".$row2['id']."&3p&".$_SESSION['username']."' href='sell.php' data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-theme='a'>Sell</a>";
    $html .= "</p>";
    $html .= "</li>";
}

$html .= "</ul>";
echo $html;
```

Any help?

Comment: debug with the firebug . Can you see whether the hasDatepicker class is active or inactive

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(...).datepicker('destroy');` on all (or all current) datepicker fields before initializing new ones.

Comment: TypeError: inst is undefined

inst.append.remove();

Comment: do you have the problem uploaded somewhere where we will be able to see it in action?

Comment: You can see it here: http://www.blinkblink.eu/tests/ login with test test. Then click on a product, then you see the date-input-box (first time)

Comment: try moving your datepicker call to `$.post({...}).complete(function() { [destroy all and initialize new datepicker stuff] });`.

Comment: also, there's a default value of "Date" on your datepicker field, try removing that.

Comment: still no result. Changes are still viewable

Comment: try changing line `$('.date').datepicker();` to `$('.date').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker();` and report back! if that doesn't work, try having a `$('datepickerfield').live('click',function({$('datepickerfield').datepicker();});` for the datepicker field in question.

Comment: I tried to remove the hasdatepickerclass before, without any succes.

When I try the live function, I get an error the second time I click the datepickerfield
TypeError: inst.dpDiv[showAnim || "show"] is not a function

Comment: yikes! sorry i couldn't help.

Comment: Thaks for trying anyway. I will keep on debugging and I will let you know when I found the solution. Cause I know I will. Just a matter of time :)

Comment: good, you're determined. i'm curious as well so do let me know.

Comment: My temporarily fix is to refresh the page when the user leaves the page, but that will slow everything down...

Comment: I kind of managed to get it to work: Everytime a dynamic page gets loaded, I manually add classes to the datepicker (like jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js does). So basically, I only have jquery datepicker running, and manually add jqm class to the elements.